# Calling code in Angular controller at intervals

Tags: angularjs

In the following code snippet, I would like to call the code inside the function at intervals (starting with `var layout_url` and ending with `fillLayoutData(xFactory, val.position, val.url, val.height, cType);`).

```
rp3.controller('c1Ctrl', [
    '$scope',
    'xFactory',
    function($scope, xFactory) {

        var layout_url = "json/dashboard/layout/mpu/layout.json";

        xFactory.getJSON(layout_url, function(layout) {// read layout's web
            // service
            $.each(layout, function(i, val) {
                chart.push({
                    "v" : val,
                    "x" : xFactory
                });
                var cType = getChartType(val.chartType);
                // alert(cType);
                drawLayout(parentDIV.name, val.position, val.width,
                        val.height, val.title, val.color, val.bgcolor,
                        buttomCtrl.withCtrl, cType);
                fillLayoutData(xFactory, val.position, val.url, val.height,
                        cType);
            });
        }, function() {
            console.log("Connection! ");
        });
    } ]);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Expose that portion of the code as a controller method, and you can do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

put part of your code in function which you want call at intervals and call it with $intervals

```
rp3.controller('c1Ctrl', [
'$scope',
'xFactory',
'$interval',
function ($scope, xFactory, $interval) {

    var layout_url = "json/dashboard/layout/mpu/layout.json";

    $scope.myIntervalFunction = function () {
        xFactory.getJSON(layout_url, function (layout) {// read layout's web
            // service
            $.each(layout, function (i, val) {
                chart.push({
                    "v": val,
                    "x": xFactory
                });
                var cType = getChartType(val.chartType);
                // alert(cType);
                drawLayout(parentDIV.name, val.position, val.width,
                    val.height, val.title, val.color, val.bgcolor,
                    buttomCtrl.withCtrl, cType);
                fillLayoutData(xFactory, val.position, val.url, val.height,
                    cType);
            });
        }, function () {
            console.log("Connection! ");
        });
    }


    var interval = $interval(function(){
      return $scope.myIntervalFunction()
     },100) 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do that is:

- injecting the `$interval` service in the controller
- wrap all theecessary code inside a method.
- use the $interval service to call the method and set a delay

**Code example:**

```js
rp3.controller('c1Ctrl', ['$scope','xFactory','$interval'
  function($scope, xFactory, $interval) {


    var layout_url = "json/dashboard/layout/mpu/layout.json";


    //1. Wrap all the necessary code inside a method
    $scope.foo = function(){
      xFactory.getJSON(layout_url, function(layout) { // read layout's web
        // service
        $.each(layout, function(i, val) {
          chart.push({
            "v": val,
            "x": xFactory
          });
          var cType = getChartType(val.chartType);
          // alert(cType);
          drawLayout(parentDIV.name, val.position, val.width,
            val.height, val.title, val.color, val.bgcolor,
            buttomCtrl.withCtrl, cType);
          fillLayoutData(xFactory, val.position, val.url, val.height,
            cType);
        });
      }, function() {
        console.log("Connection! ");
      });
    };



    //2. use $interval service. I use 2s delay (2000ms)
    $interval($scope.foo, 2000);



  }
]);
```

**Additional note:**

- You need to just wrap the `getJSON()` function, not the `layout_url` variabile, as it's not needed since its value never change.

Comment: Make sure you cancel the $interval on $scope.$destroy.

Comment: What if I want to update only `fillLayoutData(xFactory, val.position, val.url, val.height, cType);`? I tried to move the function to inside the loop but this causes the code to update only the last chart.

Comment: @BlairOsbay is I understood correctly what your problem is, it's probably because you have the each loop which iterates from the first to the last item, before the interval actually start. So because of that you see it applied only on the last item. Can you edit your original post including this new problem?